# Синхронизация данных для чтения

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Необходимо ли синхронизировать данные среди нескольких потоков, если потоки данные не изменяют. 
К примеру, вопрос отпадает если несколько потоков пытаются изменить одну и ту же переменную: 
Выносим обращение к переменной в критическую секцию и используем что-нибудь а-ля мьютекса для корректной записи. 
А если потоки только читают данные? Необходимо ли синхронизировать чтение и что случится если этого не делать? 
Поправьте меня, если вопрос задан некорректно, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если данные статичны и только читают то нет

Comment: @Arenoros а что имеется в виду под статичностью данных?

Comment: То что данные не изменяются пока работают потоки

Comment: @Arenoros понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Синхронизуют всегда с какой-то целью. В случае, когда все только читают данные, то синхронизовывать нужно только при обновлении данных - чтобы полностью обновить данные и потом все читали одно и то же.